# Access violation when assigning an uninitialized iterator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with assigning an unintialized to an initialized iterator. The following code excerpt produces an access violation when built with Visual Studio 2010. In previous versions of Visual Studio the code should work.

```
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> list;
    std::list<int>::iterator it = list.begin();
    std::list<int>::iterator jt;
    it = jt; // crashes in VS 2010
}
```

Wouldn't this be considered valid C++?

I need this code to implement a "cursor" class that either points nowhere or to a specific element in a list. What else could I use as a value for an uninitialized iterator if I don't have a reference to my container yet?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  You initialise `it` to point at something valid, and then you immediately overwrite it with an undefined value?

Comment: Your comments don't match your code: did you intend to type jt=it; instead in your code?  If so, that should work fine.

Comment: You can't use `jt` for anything. You can't even swap the thing: `std::swap(it,jt)` will produce the same error on VS2010.

Comment: @MSalters: `std::swap(it, jt)` might not produce the same error, for it is UB. So there is no such guarantee.

Comment: @Nawaz: That's why I actually tested it, and qualified the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 it = jt; // crashes in VS 2010
```

This invokes undefined behaviour (UB). According to the C++ Standard ,`jt` is a **singular** iterator which is not associated with any container, and results of most expressions are undefined for singular iterator.

The section §24.1/5 from the C++ Standard (2003) reads (see the **bold** text specifically),

> Just as a regular pointer to an array
>   guarantees that there is a pointer
>   value pointing past the last element
>   of the array, so for any iterator type
>   there is an iterator value that points
>   past the last element of a
>   corresponding container. These values
>   are called past-the-end values. Values
>   of an iterator i for which the
>   expression *i is defined are called
>   dereferenceable. The library never
>   assumes that past-the-end values are
>   dereferenceable. **Iterators can also
>   have singular values that are not
>   associated with any container.**
>   [Example: After the declaration of an
>   uninitialized pointer x (as with int*
>   x;), x must always be assumed to have
>   a singular value of a pointer.]
>   **Results of most expressions are
>   undefined for singular values;** the
>   only exception is an assignment of a
>   non-singular value to an iterator that
>   holds a singular value. In this case
>   the singular value is overwritten the
>   same way as any other value.
>   Dereferenceable values are always
>   nonsingular.

If MSVS2010 crashes this, it is one of infinite possibilities of UB, for UB means anything could happen; the Standard doesn't prescribe any behavior.

Comment: Why is `jt` uninitialized? It is not a basic data type but has a constructor that is called.

Comment: @fschoenm: See my answer now. It is more complete now.

Answer (score 2):

C++11, 24.2.1/3:

> Results of most expressions are undefined for singular values; the
>   only exceptions are destroying an iterator that holds a singular
>   value, the assignment of a non-singular value to an iterator that
>   holds a singular value, and, for iterators that satisfy the
>   DefaultConstructible requirements, using a value-initialized iterator
>   as the source of a copy or move operation.

The list is limitative, and your example isn't listed in the allowed exceptions. `jt` is singular and default-initialized. Therefore it may not be used as the source of a copy operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a KNOWN value to use a signal. You don't have that unless you have a container to get .end() from, which you think is your problem.

What you really need to do is get away from thinking that you can use 'special' iterator values for oddball cases that don't involve a container. Iterators, while they work a lot like pointers, are NOT pointers. They don't have the equivalent of 'NULL'.

Instead, use a boolean flag value to see if the container is set or not, and make sure the iterators (all of them, if you have more than one) get set to some valid value when the container becomes known, and the flag gets set back to false when you lose the container. Then you can check the flag before any iterator operations.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that. The problem in my case occurred in the default assignment operator.

Answer (score -1):

`list.end()` points anywhere beyond the container, so we can consider it like pointing nowhere.
Also accessing unitialized variable causes undefined behavior.

Comment: It's default-initialized, not un initialized. And `list.end()` points to a particular list, which means the iterator is invalidated when that list is destroyed.